# Vue3 - Function that changes a property input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am currently building a Vue application utilizing a map. The functionality is basically this. I have a position on the map and an algorythm to determine weather that position is over water or over land. If it is over water I want to reiterate over random positions nearby until my position is over land and return those coordinates. So basically my (very rudimentary for testing it out first) code looks similar to this

**snippet from template**

```html
<mapbox-marker :lngLat="getPositionOverLand([0,5])" />
```

**corresponding code**

```js
const getPositonOverLand = (coords: any, tries=100) => {
      
const newCoords = [coords[0], coords[1]] as [number, number];
      let thisTry = 0;
      while(isOverWater(newCoords) && thisTry < tries){
        newCoords[0] = coords[0] + (Math.random() - 0.5)*0.5
        newCoords[1] = coords[1] + (Math.random() - 0.5)*0.5
        thisTry++;
      }
      if(thisTry === tries)
        throw new Error('No position on land nearby could be found');
  

      coords[0] = newCoords[0];
      coords[1] = newCoords[1];
    }
```

Now I debugged the algorythm and it works just fine. Usually after 5 or so attempts a position on land has been found and is returned. I also implemented a parameter for maximum tries so if a position on the open ocean e.g. is beeing put in an error is thrown after a certain number of attempts.

Now my problem in vue is this. If I change the coordinates in my function (it does not matter if I use a return statement or change the coordinates in the array) the function will be triggered again leaving me with an infinite loop.

Is there any possibility to prevent that behaviour and make sure the algorythm will only be run once or did I miss something else.

Strangly I also tried to just return the given coords just for testing and this does not cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's triggering the reactivity. From the code posted, there is no way to tell since there are no reactive variables in sight, so it might be caused by something further upstream.

However, I see this: `<mapbox-marker :lngLat="getPositionOverLand([0,5])" />` as a *code smell* when it comes to vue, because it has the potential to cause the type of issues you are seeing.

When you are passing a function result into as a parameter the function will re-run every time any of the parents triggers a re-render. And if you have anything in that function that triggers a re-render (which doesn't seem to be the case here, but I'm not seeing a return so I know it's not shown in entirety).

The better way to do this is to use a `computed`, or a `data` that gets updated through a `watch` that way the value is stored and a change is only made as needed.

Comment: Yes that's what I expected too. However computed was not really a possibility since I need to be able to use an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Alright,

as pointed out already the problem is that every mutation on the position will trigger another reender (which still does not explain though why a direct return of the parameter itsself in the function didn't result in the same behaviour).

However I was able to solve my problem. Now I will post a little more code than included in my original question since another component with asynchronous behavior is involved. So my html looks like this

```html
<mapbox-map :accessToken="myToken" @loaded="updateMyPosition">
  <mapbox-marker :lngLat="myPosition" />
</mapbox-map>
```

Now the position needs to be a ref which will be updated once the map is loaded and available. This will ensure the data is only mutated once instead of the function beeing run over and over again.

I also changed the getPositionOverLand function a little bit but the functionality is basically the same as before. I just preferred the recursive variant over the while loop.

```js
const myPosition = ref([10,10]);

const getPositionOverLand = (coords, currentTry=0, maxTries=100) => {
  if(!isOverWater(coords))
    return coords;

  let newCoords = [
    coords[0] + (Math.random() - 0.5)*0.5,
    coords[1] + (Math.random() - 0.5)*0.5
  ];

  if(currentTry >= maxTries)
    throw new Error('No position on land could be found');

   return (isOverWater(newCoords) && currentTry < maxTries)
      ? getPositonOverLand(coords, currentTry+1, maxTries)
      : newCoords;
}

const updateMyPosition = map => {
  myPosition.value = getPositionOverLand(myPosition.value);
}
```

Now while this is working I still think it is not pretty. I would prefer to use the function instead of mutation the ref because in that way working with a v-for for example would be significantly cleaner as it would be to iterate over that array in code and change each value.

For now I will make this the answer but if someone comes up with a cleaner way to do this I'd be more than happy to change the accepted answer ;)